# async/await in a class method called "then"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, promise

I created a class that has a "then" method. This class is unrelated to the Promise type; the "then" method has a different purpose and doesn't return a promise. I am trying to write an async/await function in Typescript 2.1.4 that awaits and returns an instance of this class, but the Typescript server in VS Code is giving me errors. If I rename the method to something other than "then", the errors go away.

Example code with errors:

```
class MyClass {
    then(): number {
        // this method isn't related to Promise.then
        return 2 + 2;
    }
}

// three errors below go away when "then" is renamed

// [ts] An async function or method must have a valid awaitable return type.
async function my_async(): Promise<MyClass> {
    let a: Promise<MyClass> = Promise.resolve(new MyClass());

    // [ts] Operand for 'await' does not have a valid callable 'then' member.
    let b: MyClass = await a;

    // [ts] Return expression in async function does not have a valid callable 'then' member.
    return b;
}
```

Can someone explain why using promises with an object that has its own "then" method is not allowed, or a work around?

Comment: You didn't say what the error is. That's rather important.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks, my bad!

Comment: Please post the code as well. The error seems to be regarding your return type.

Comment: @Carcigenicate updated with example code, hopefully this clears everything up!

Comment: it seems a bit odd to have a `.then` method that isn't from a promise.

Comment: @DanielA.White I was writing a Transaction class, and I wanted the method to merge and combine Transactions to be named "then". I'm not sure if this is a typescript server bug or if my understanding of promises and async/await needs improvement

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not, I'm awaiting a promise that resolves an instance of MyClass. Let me update the example code to make that more clear.

Comment: @drdrez Nice minimal example! Unfortunately, Ive never used async/await before, but hopefully the question is clear enough for someone with experience to help you.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah, thanks for your help! I haven't used SO in a while, I should probably read up on the rules and guidelines.

Comment: @drdrez Just remember, when you come here with a question, post any errors you get, and a minimal example that shows the problem. You seem to understand that though. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `then` method *is* related to the Promise API - from the JavaScript ducktyping point of view, your class is a `thenable` see [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promiseresolvethenablejob), specifically [this step](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions)

```
...
Let then be Get(resolution, "then").
...
```

If your promise resolves to an object that has a `then` function, then it has a special meaning - it's a `thenable`. You cannot yield result objects that have a `then` function and not have them treated by the Promise resolution algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Promises are defined as objects that have a method called `.then`. They are not defined, for instance, as "the module returned by `require('bluebird/promise')`".

Part of what makes this important is that when a promise library is resolving a promise, it is not meant to offer up the final result inside of a call to `.then` if that result is a promise itself. For instance:

```
function myFn() {
  // doPromise1 will eventually give us `1`.
  return doPromise1().then(x => {
    // doPromise2 will eventually give us `2`.
    return doPromise2();
  });
}
```

Calling this function and calling `.then` on the result won't return the promise I got inside of `doPromise2()`. It will return `2` - so it will wait until both promises finish, and give that final value.

This is different from if I had returned `3` inside of `then`. It would see that the result is not a promise, and offer up that as the final value. However, the crux of the issue is how it knows that that is not a promise. It doesn't do typechecking, like `if p instanceof Promise` because there are too many Promise definitions and polyfills in various libraries, and they're meant to work together. Instead, they check something generic that should look like this: `if (typeof p.then === 'function')`.

That check is returning `true` for your class, and this causes it to think your value is a Promise itself. It runs it, hoping to get back another promise object, but gets a number and fails.